# Gnuplot - how to join two files using only common data

Tags: linux, graph, gnuplot, monitoring

I need plot graph from two input files where is always x axis time (00:00-23:59) with data minute by minute. In one file is complete full range (time between 00:00 - 23:59), in second always different range (let say 01:45 - 2:45) - which is variable (I am using gnuplot as monitoring). How to join these two files to plot only common part?

Thank you

Standa

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have a file a.dat which contains data from 00:00 to 23:59, like this:

```
# a.dat
...
01:01  1
01:02  2
01:03  3
01:04  4
01:05  5
01:06  6
01:07  7
01:08  8
...
```

and a file b.dat which contains data for a variable time range, like this:

```
# b.dat
01:04 4.2
01:05 5.2
01:06 6.2
```

You can use something like the following script to plot both files using the time range of the second one:

```
# Prepare for plotting time data
set timefmt "%H:%M"
set xdata time
set format x "%H:%M"

# The 'stats' command does not work for time data. So we make a 
# 'dummy' plot of the smaller file, b.dat. This will store the 
# xrange in the variables GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN/MAX.
plot "b.dat" using 1:2

# Prepare the real plot.
set terminal pngcairo
set output "data.png"

# Explicitly set xrange of file b.dat
set xrange [GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN:GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX]

# The actual plot:
plot "a.dat" using 1:2  w lp ls 6, "b.dat" using 1:2  w p ls 7
```

And this is the output with my test data: 
[image: plot two files with xrange of the smaller one]